# How can I overwrite a file or prevent 'copy' from being appended?

Tags: filesystem, copy-paste

When I copy/paste a file into a folder where a  file with the same name exists, instead of replacing, it changes the filename to 'file Copy'.
Is there a way to copy/replace similar to windows or ubuntu?

I am using OSX 10.8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in OS X Mavericks, dragging a file into a folder that contains a file with the same name will prompt you for what you would like to do.

Take, for example, these two folders: `Folder1` and `Folder2`. Both contain a text file called `Test.txt`.

Dragging `Test.txt` from `Folder1` into `Folder2` will result in this dialog:

[image: Copy/Replace]

"Keep Both" will result in the file being named `Test copy.txt`. "Replace" does exactly what you want - replaces `Folder2/Test.txt` with `Folder1`'s `Test.txt`.

---

As user dval has discovered, earlier versions of OS X may require that you hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd> while you drag a file into another folder in order to see the "Replace" option.

Comment: Is there anyway to mimic that behavior in older osx versions?  I only see that dialog if I am dragging multiple files. It seems like an inconsistency in the OS. For a single file, if I drag or cmd-c/cmd-v, it just renames without prompt.

Comment: I am unsure - I only have Mavericks installed on my machines. Try dragging while holding option. Or holding cmd? Try them all!

Comment: @aglasser I like your style - "Try them all" 

Comment: cmd seemed to bring up the dialog. now, it works as expected. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad to help.